# canvas fill - spaces between shapes (antialias)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have problem, and yet no idea how to solve it.
Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/ctt4f6ox/ .

HTML

```
<canvas id="tester"></canvas>
```

CSS

```
#tester{
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    background: #000;
}
```

JS

```
var c = $('#tester');
var cdom = c[0];
var ctx = cdom.getContext('2d');
cdom.width = cdom.height = ctx.width = ctx.height = 160;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
ctx.lineTo(100,20);
ctx.lineTo(60,80);
ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineTo(140,80);
ctx.lineTo(100,20);
ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.fill();
```

As you can see, there is black line between two triangles caused by antialiasing. I want to make in canvas something like [this](http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/abstract-background-made-by-colorful-triangles_279-14738.jpg) random image, but i keep getting gaps between triangles. Only way fixing this is making triangles larger to overlap them, but it gets uneven/irregular. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not fill backround with black, leave it transparent, and fill every space with triangles.

```js
var c = $('#tester');
var cdom = c[0];
var ctx = cdom.getContext('2d');
cdom.width = cdom.height = ctx.width = ctx.height = 160;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
ctx.lineTo(100,20);
ctx.lineTo(60,80);
ctx.fillStyle="green";
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(60,80);
ctx.lineTo(140,80);
ctx.lineTo(100,20);
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fill();
```

```css
#tester{
 width: 160px;
 height: 160px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="tester"></canvas>
```

2. Or repeat paint operation for every triangle 3 times - http://jsfiddle.net/ctt4f6ox/1/

Comment: Solution 1 is giving same effect, if you zoom in, you will see transparent gap between triangles. However solution 2, maybe not most efficient, but can be good walk around if there wont be better solution. Thanks for answer.